# Retrieve audio from gallery using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Hi In my android phonegap app,i have used voice plugin to record the audio and its storing into "mnt/sdcard/DCIM/FolderName/" .But when i try to retrieve audio from that folder i get only image and video.Please help me to retrieve audio from gallery.

Here is my code for retrieving audio:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality:
    50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: source,
    mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

get the help from this link  it might help you what u need..

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

// Retrieve image file location from specified source something like this..

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
```

Comment: I have used destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,and souceType:navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY.Is this correct to retrieve audio.

Comment: I dont know how to choose media library.Please help me.

Comment: @JavaH look at this link http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/05/using-media-class-in-phonegap.html

Comment: in that link they have directly passing the file name and playing.But i need to browse the audio from the sdcard...

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge Audio data is not represented in the Gallery app. Only image and video which Camera.getPicture() will allow you to access.

Can you provide more information on what you mean by "retrieve audio"? Do you just need the path or do you need to play the audio, etc.